# GI want torep with inotify

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, inotify

I want to filter inotify results, but last grep don't return anything.

```sh
inotifywait . --recursive --monitor --event CREATE --event MODIFY  --event DELETE | grep -Eiv "excludefolder" | grep -Eo ".*"
```

At the same time this works ok:

```sh
 echo "./v2-test/ MODIFY 1.php  MODIFY clickhouse-server.log" | grep -Eiv "excludefolder" | grep -Eo ".*"
```

Comment: Try adding `--line-buffered` or `stdbuf -oL` to `grep`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it works!!! Make an answer